# Subdomain redirecting to subdirectory via dns/cname?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, cname

We're looking at running bigcommerce for a website and they have the ability to run the store using your primary domain url (which we don't want to do) or a subdomain. We wanted to have for eg: http://www.ourwebsite.com/shop.

Bigcommerce doesn't have the capability of us running it on a subdirectory, aside from a subdomain.

**Can we with dns records point our subdirectory as above to load contents from our subdomain? If so, how?**

ie: http://shop.ourwebsite.com/ contents displayed on http://www.ourwebsite.com/shop

We also have to use cname records to make our shop.ourwebsite.com subdomain load the contents from bigcommerce (I assume this is how it's done using your own url rather than their own yoururl.bigcommerce.com url).
We need to ensure this can still remain in place and it doesn't affect the above change we require.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Use mod_proxy this way your url stays the same (available through mod_rewirte [[P]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) flag).
- Redirect to your subdomain (html-meta, htaccess/http reply 301/302, frameset/iframe which is really ugly)

But with pure DNS, it's not possible.
CNAME DNS entries are just aliases for other domains, but can't handle directory structures.